# I want to retrieve different documents from firebase based on the current index of the listwheelview

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Am trying to retrive documents from firebase, but the thing is, I want the user to scroll throw my listwheelview and by each scroll it will retrieve a document from [[the UI am trying to bulid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvj8w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMVzo.png)firebase based on the index of the listwheelview(starts from 0)

the idea of my app is that the pregnant women can view the baby's development picture, height and weight week by week(listwheelview)

It's so confusing for me so if anyone can help I would be so thankful!

below is my listwheelview code

```
int currentIndex = 0;
  double itemWidth = 60.0;
  int itemCount = 40;
  int batchSize = 1;
  int selected = 2;
  FixedExtentScrollController _scrollController =
      FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 50);

      
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 180,
            child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: -1,
                child: ListWheelScrollView(
                  magnification: 2.0,
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (x) {
                    currentIndex = x;
                    setState(() {
                      selected = x;
                    });
                    print(selected);
                  },
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  children: List.generate(
                      itemCount,
                      (x) => RotatedBox(
                          quarterTurns: 1,
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                              width: x == selected ? 70 : 60,
                              height: x == selected ? 80 : 70,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: x == selected
                                      ? Color.fromRGBO(249, 220, 222, 1)
                                      : Colors.transparent,
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                              child: Text(
                                'week \n \n    ${x + 1}', // so it starts from week 1
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Urbanist'),
                              )))),
                  itemExtent: itemWidth,
                )),
```